# Basic Auth is not working with Axios post Nodejs

Tags: node.js, post, axios

I am trying to send a request using axios post with basic authorization. It is working fine with postman but not working when I try to send via code.

```
axios.post(`my-url`, {
headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Authorization': 'Basic **KEY_HERE**',
},
data: {
 'id': 'event_order',
 'date': '2021-09-09'
}
}).then(async (response) => {
console.log(response.data)
})
```

It is returning 401 Unauthorized. But, it works as excepted when I call it via Postman:

[Postman Setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNVjw.png)

Answer (score -1):

Did you add your domain to whitelist in your cors module? If not:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "PROTOCOL://DOMAIN:PORT", credentials: true }));
```

edit: Ok, sorry, I was confused and thought you were sending a frontend axios post request to your own NodeJS server. If possible, could you be more precise. But try passing in your headers/auth as the third argument-- since you're passing in everything in the second argument, the API is not parsing out your headers since its part of the data parameter.

```
const data = {
  'id': 'event_order',
  'date': '2021-09-09'
}
axios.post(`my-url`, data, {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  auth: {
    username: "YOUR_USERNAME",
    password: "YOUR_PASS"
  }
})
.then(async (response) => {
  console.log(response.data)
})
```

Also try and post the network errors, if you can.

Comment: The [tag:node.js] tag indicates this code will be run server-side; CORS is thus not a consideration. Further it is not clear if the OP controls the server that's being called with `axios` and would have sufficient control to make changes to the CORS configuration of said server.

Comment: Ah, I see. Seemed like it was worded to suggest "axios posting to NodeJS server" with the `my-url` indicating he was in control of said server. Wish he worded it a bit more carefully.

Comment: I do not have control to change in API ie my-url. @GandalfTheGrey